# Brave/Sleuth Traceid in @JMSListner

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am sending some messages to embedded activemq in Springboot application. I have Sleuth/Brave for distributed tracing.

While I see tracerId before sending the request in Producer method.

> 2020-03-16 15:59:40.539 -  INFO [test-framework-api,6e8c40901e5ea627,7c9ba94387317bea,true] - setting jms before sending

After it is dequeued from @JMSListener, it just looses the traceId

> 2020-03-16 15:59:40.550 -  INFO [test-framework-api,,,] - ----Received ActiveMQ Message-----

How do I retain it in receiveMessage side?

The following is the related dependencies, I am using:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq:2.2.1.RELEASE")
compile("org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.15.10")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin")
```

[Sample Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbZej.png)

Comment: I have no idea which version of Sleuth you're using. This is the class / object that is responsible for JMS handling https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/TraceMessagingAutoConfiguration.java . You can also double check in the broker that the message indeed gets instrumented.

Comment: Thanks Marcin,  I am using 

compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin")
with 
dependencyManagement {
 val springCloudVersion = "Finchley.SR2"
 imports {
  mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:$springCloudVersion")
 }
}

Comment: Please update to the latest stable release and try again

Comment: I added the following and still no luck  
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:2.2.2.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth:2.2.2.RELEASE")

Just wondering , if the class you added has incuded ActiveMQ as well ? Coz' I could see Kafka and RabbitMQ related imports only.

Thanks

Comment: I think we'll need a sample to check this out

Comment: If I understand this ticket correctly https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/issues/778 , then there is no support for spring embedded activemq yet

Comment: I managed to get it working with using artemis `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis` & `org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-server`.
Important to note is, that the JmsTemplate must be configured to send the tracing logs. But if you use the autoconfiguration, then spring-boot does its magic for you.